# Equivalent of filter:Glow(Color=#000000, strength=2); for Firefox

Tags: css

Can anyone please tell me the equivalent of `filter:Glow(Color=#000000, strength=2);` for Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're either looking for

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
```

or

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
```

You might need to stick a vendor prefix onto that.